# Python: List Comprehension With unicode validaton

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let say I have a list that contains string: ta, fa, ba, ut and lets call our list to be `some_list = ['ta', 'fa', 'ba', 'ut']`

What I want to do is, in pseudocode:

```
for x in some_list:
    if unicode(x, 'utf-8') == another_unicoded_string:
       do something:
```

But I want to do it using list comprehension the pythonic way:

So This is how I did but this not really working:

```
if [x for x in some_list if unicode(x, 'utf-8') == 'te']:
```

in above case it shouldn't match so shouldn't really go into the loop based on what I have written It doesn't go into the statement in either ways:

Comment: List comprehension should only really be used if you want a list to be returned. If you just want to execute some code if your list elements meet a particular criterion, then just use a `for`-loop.

Comment: Output of [x for x in...] is a list which is always true if it has anything in it. (e.g if [False]: statement... always is true and executes the statement)To check elements of a list or do operations on them you have to consult "any", "all" , "map" , "filter" etc...

Comment: Furthermore, your "pseudocode" version is easier to understand and more efficient than any list comprehension-based solution will be.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
for x in (x for x in some_list if unicode(x, 'utf-8') == 'te'):
    do_something
```

or (less efficiently - thanks jamaylak for the suggestion),

```
for x in [x for x in some_list if unicode(x, 'utf-8') == 'te']:
    do_something
```

Comment: I'd suggest switching this to a generator `for x in (x for x in some_list if unicode(x, 'utf-8') == 'te'):`

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing returns a filtered list. So my guess is that you are trying to do something like this.

```
[do_something(x) for x in some_list if unicode(x, 'utf-8') == u'te']
```

Being a bit more verbose:

```
>>> some_list
['ta', 'fa', 'ba', 'te', 'ut', 'te']
>>> [x for x in some_list if unicode(x, 'utf-8') == u'te']
['te', 'te']
>>> [unicode(x) for x in some_list if unicode(x, 'utf-8') == u'te']
[u'te', u'te']
```

Comment: I thought of that answer too @Alex, but the downside is storing the results. The OP doesn't specify what's to be done (and whether they want the results).

Comment: Well it's always good showing the functional programming capabilities of Python ;)

Comment: Haha, well ok, as long as `do something` isn't `print x` in Python 2x ;)

Comment: I see, I thought there is away to just get single element rather than getting a list in the list comprehension.